# Checkbox onclick function for filling input field

Tags: jquery, html, date, checkbox

I have "enter date" text input field in my registration form. Is there anyway, to put checkbox "Today" near the input field "date" and fill current date ontick, clear on untick? P.S Format must be DD.MM.YYYY

Comment: You should be careful when you 'clear on untick' - you won't know if the user has changed the value after selecting 'today', unless you specifically code for that. For example, the user may click 'Today', then change the day '+1' to quickly get 'tomorrow'. IN this instance, the checkbox for 'today' will still be checked, and the date will not be 'today'. Then, if the user clears the checkbox, their date will be deleted entirely. Not good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your checkbox has id="todayBox" and your date field has id="enterDate", you would use this jQuery code:

```
$("#todayBox").change(function() {
    var dateStr;
    if (this.checked) {
        var now = new Date();
        dateStr = now.getDate() + "." + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "." + now.getFullYear();
    } else {
        dateStr = "";
    }
    $("#enterDate").val(dateStr);
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/d3t5Z/.

Comment: please create working example on jsfiddle if it's possible. and how to clear on untick?

Comment: I changed the code to be a checkbox and I now have a jsFiddle that shows it.  I had difficulty understanding your question.  Next time it would be easy to understand if you include the HTML.

Comment: Come on now.  Can't you complete that last part and figure out how to add a leading zero if the day or month string is only one char in length?  We aren't here to write every single detail for you.  We've shown you how to do it and given you a working example and shown you how to manage the checkbox and shown you how to format a date.  Show us that you're willing to do a little work yourself.  If you have an honest question about how to add a leading zero AFTER you've tried, then you can ask that question and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Also, your question did not clearly state that you wanted leading zeroes as DD.MM.YYYY doesn't always mean leading zeroes are desired.  Sometimes, it's used to just show you want day.month.year.

Comment: What are you talking about? it's 13.9.2011

Comment: why doe it show wrong date on my browser? it shows 2.8.2011 instead of 13.9.2011

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3390/discussion-between-tural-teyyuboglu-and-jfriend00)

Comment: OK, corrected two minor errors.  It should give you `13.9.2011` now (if it's past midnight where you are).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#Today").click(GetDate);

});

function GetDate() {
 if (formatted_date == null) {
  var d = new Date();
  var formatted_date = d.getDate() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getFullYear());
  $("#DateTextBoxID").val(formatted_date);
 }
 else {
  $("#DateTextBoxID").val("");
 }
}
```

Comment: Working examples are definitely _not_ required for answers. It's nice if the author provides them, but you should be prepared to apply their examples to your own code, especially in a simple case like this.

Comment: I don't have an account with jsfiddle currently

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox doesn't feel like the right control for this. If you're using HTML5, I would suggest a `command` element, otherwise, a `<button type="button">` element. Either way, give it a class, and then attach some javascript via the class. It's not a bad idea to use an attribute to link the button/command element to the date field - `rel=""` is often used for this, even though it's not its intended purpose. Linking the two this way would allow you to have multiple date fields and 'today' controls on the same page, without hard-coding their names.

The HTML for this would look like:

```
<label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
<input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"/>
<button type="button" class="setDateToday" rel="dateOfBirth">Today</button>
```

And jQuery'd javascript:

```
$(function(){
   $('button.setDateToday').click(function(){
      //Format today's date:
      var today = new Date(),
          todayFormat = today.getDay() + '.' + today.getMonth() + '.' + today.getFullYear();

      //Find the input indicated by the rel attribute and set the value
      $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).val(todayFormat);
   });
});
```

The reason you shouldn't 'clear the date on clear checkbox' is that the user may have pushed 'today', then altered the date. Clearing the value may well undo their work.  The checkbox itself isn't a very clear indicator of what will happen when you check it - whereas a button clearly indicates that some action will be taken when you click.